# Armature: bone rotating other bones when moved!

Tags: animation, armature

Is anyone here that knows armatures?

I'm having a major problem with one of my bones and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I've rebuilt this armature a dozen times and I still run into the same issue! For a couple of weeks now I'm frustrated to tears almost!

I cannot get the bone to **not** rotate the wings no matter what I do, but it's the main armature bone!

https://youtu.be/X1AXJWoRzGo

Comment: The wings are nailed by IK from what i can see. So of course they rotate too when you pull the rootbone away. You could try to add a rotation constraint. But this is guessing, since we don't know the rig.

Comment: A rotation constraint wow did not think about that!

Comment: Should the wings be separated from the rest of the armature?

Comment: Doesn't an IK's pole target control the rotation?

Comment: when you move the root bone, the targets for the IK don´t move. Try moving those as well, I think that should solve your problem.